# @DynamoDBIndexHashKey must specify one of HASH GSI name/names

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

My Class is as Follows

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = LogConstant.TableName)
public class Journal {

@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "event_type")
private String eventType;

@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "user_id",globalSecondaryIndexName = LogConstant.GlobalUserIdIndex)
private String userId;

@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "user_identifier", globalSecondaryIndexName = LogConstant.GlobalUserIdentifierIndex)
private String userIdentifier;

@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "order_id", globalSecondaryIndexName = LogConstant.GlobalOrderIdIndex)
private String orderId;

@DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "generated_by")
private GenertionType generatedBy;

@DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "interacting_service")
private InteractingService interactingSerice;

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "agent")
private String agent;

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "content")
private String content;

@DynamoDBRangeKey
@DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(attributeName = "created_at",
        globalSecondaryIndexNames = {LogConstant.GlobalUserIdIndex,LogConstant.GlobalUserIdentifierIndex,LogConstant.GlobalOrderIdIndex})
private String createdAt;
```

The service getting the search result is

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<Journal> expression = new 
DynamoDBQueryExpression<Journal>()
            .withIndexName(LogConstant.GlobalUserIdIndex)
            .withConsistentRead(false)
            .withHashKeyValues(journal);

    TableDescription table = DynamoDbStarter.getDynamoDB().getTable(LogConstant.TableName).describe();

    return DynamoDbStarter.getDynamoDBMapper().query(Journal.class, expression);
```

Even Though the insert is working normally but during fetching the result I am getting an exception

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: @DynamoDBIndexHashKey must specify one of HASH GSI name/names
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardAnnotationMaps$FieldMap.globalSecondaryIndexNames(StandardAnnotationMaps.java:345) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel$Properties$Immutable.<init>(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:459) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$Bean.<init>(StandardBeanProperties.java:92) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$Bean.<init>(StandardBeanProperties.java:86) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$BeanMap.putOrFlatten(StandardBeanProperties.java:217) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$BeanMap.putAll(StandardBeanProperties.java:207) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$BeanMap.<init>(StandardBeanProperties.java:198) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$CachedBeans.getBeans(StandardBeanProperties.java:55) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$CachedBeans.access$100(StandardBeanProperties.java:48) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties.of(StandardBeanProperties.java:42) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$TableBuilder.<init>(StandardModelFactories.java:132) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$TableBuilder.<init>(StandardModelFactories.java:116) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$StandardTableFactory.getTable(StandardModelFactories.java:107) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.getTableModel(DynamoDBMapper.java:393) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.createQueryRequestFromExpression(DynamoDBMapper.java:1626) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.query(DynamoDBMapper.java:1503) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.query(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:265) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.172.jar:na]
at com.furlenco.platform.loggingservice.service.impl.LogServiceimpl.getLogsBasedOnSecondaryIndexUserId(LogServiceimpl.java:86) ~[classes/:na]
at com.furlenco.platform.loggingservice.service.impl.LogServiceimpl.getEventLogsForUserId(LogServiceimpl.java:67) ~[classes/:na]
```

I have table with hash key as interacting_service and range key as CreatedDate. I am trying to fetch result by GSI But somehow It is resulting in an exception
Can Somebody see what is it that I am doing wrong

Comment: The `eventType` has the `@DynamoDBIndexHashKey` annotation, but the annotation is missing the index name. If you want `eventType` to be the hash key of the main table, you need to use `@DynamoDBHashKey`.

Comment: Sorry I wrongly mentioned event type it is interacting service that has the @DynamoDBHashKey annotation. I have updated the question sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception message says

```
@DynamoDBIndexHashKey must specify one of HASH GSI name/names
```

If you look at all of the `@DynamoDBIndexHashKey` annotations in your class, you will see that they all set a value for `globalSecondaryIndexName` except for the annotation on `eventType`. If `eventType` is supposed to be a GSI hash key, then you need to set this value. If `eventType` is not supposed to be the hash key of a GSI, then you need to remove the `@DynamoDBIndexHashKey` annotation from that field.

See the [javadoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBIndexHashKey.html) for more details on the usage of `@DynamoDBImdexHashKey`.

Comment: Hey Thanks. I missed that. Thanks again

Comment: It must look like this> @get:DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "product",       globalSecondaryIndexName = "product-index")
>    var product: String? = null

Answer (score -1):

It must look like this:

```
@get:DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "product", globalSecondaryIndexName = "product-index")
var product: String? = null
```

Add this also to the DB definition:

```
CreateTableRequest()

 ...

 .withGlobalSecondaryIndexes(GlobalSecondaryIndex()
            .withIndexName(PRODUCT_INDEX)
            .withKeySchema(
               KeySchemaElement(PRODUCT, KeyType.HASH),
               KeySchemaElement(PRODUCT_RANGE, KeyType.RANGE))
            .withProjection(Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.ALL))
            .withProvisionedThroughput(ProvisionedThroughput(1L, 2L)))
```